# image cropping in android

Tags: android, uiimageview, crop

i am calling a webservice by passing an customerid as parameter. The webservice returns me bits of images which i will use on android application. Now the problem is I cant use the image as it is i.e. coming from webserver because its too big. I need to crop it. If anyone has code snippet that can help i really would be thankful. Any alternative approach is also welcome.

```
try
{
byte[] imageis = getImage();

Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageis,0,imageis.length);
if (bmp!=null)
{
ImageView imgview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vimg);
imgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
}
```

getImage() method is good and working. SO no worry for that. Any one has an idea wht i need to do after this??

Answer (score 1):

I think this method may help you

It resizes a bitmap.

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: the bitmap you receive from byte[] imageis = getImage();

Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageis,0,imageis.length);

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    .....  
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByte, 0, imageByte.length, options);
    int width_tmp = options.outWidth, height_tmp = options.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < width || height_tmp / 2 < height)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }
    options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = scale;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;

    Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByte, 0, imageByte.length, options);
    ....
```

where width and height - size of your ImageView

Comment: Thanks i will try this for sure. I guess this should work but i m unsure of few variables. Will tell u if am stuck in this while implementing it. Thanks